# Using a Macro to create a summary view of financials

Tags: vba, excel

I have 100 tabs which are financials of different facilities (all financial tabs are identical) and they list the revenue, expenses, etc down column A.  I want to write a Macro or something that can take each tab and put that information horizontally into a summary tab so that my tab names will be going down column A with the revenue expenses, etc going across the top in row 1. I can write a simple macro that does 1 sheet at a time but I can't seem to get it to loop so it will continue doing the rest of the worksheets in the book. Does anyone know the code for this?

Thanks!

Jeff

Comment: Please revise the question with your code included.  Also, include the details of where the data you want to copy is originally (row, col).  Thanks.  names of sheets, or at least the format for how you name them

Comment: I have the code ready to go when you are.  Just make sure you are specific about WHERE THE SUMMARY INFO STARTS..

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need some variation on this concept:  If you could provide the information requested in the comments of the OP, it could be more accurate.  This example is assuming your summary info on each page is Row 2.  If it isn't look for the line saying "assuming your data is row 2" and change the row from 2 to the actual row.

Also, you might have issues if you have other sheets in the Workbook that aren't to be included in the summary.  If I knew how you named your sheets, I could help.  You could test each of the sheets in the workbook for something, like if it is hidden or not.  Or just check the name..  Do the first characters of ws.Name = something specific?   You would need to un-Comment the IF statement and the End If, and include a real test for the IF at that stage.

As is, this will include EVERY Sheet, including the Summary Sheet that you are creating.  It will involve you going through the Summary sheet and making sure only sheets you want got copied.

```
Sub SummaryBuilder() 
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim lRow As Long  
    'Set your Summary Sheet up with Header Rows to match your Source Sheets
    lastCol = Sheets("Summary").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lRow = 2

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        'If ws passes test Then  'If Left(ws.Name, 4) = "2014" for example or If ws.Visible = True
            Sheets("Summary").Cells(lRow, 1) = ws.Name      'Sets Column A with NAME of Sheet

            For lCol = 2 To lastCol                         'Loops through all summary columns
                Sheets("Summary").Cells(lRow, lCol) = Sheets(ws).Cells(2, lCol)  'Assuming your data is Row 2
            Next lCol
            lRow = lRow + 1
        'End If     
    Next ws
End Sub
```